# How can I sort files by DESC order with Symfony Finder Component?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-components, symfony-finder

By default [Symfony Finder Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html#sorting) sorts files by `ASC` order.

```
//sorting by ASC order
$finder->files()->in($this->getDumpPath())->sortByModifiedTime();
```

How can I sort files by `DESC`?

Comment: symfony finder component cant do this , you must sort by desc after get result

Comment: You may also use the `sort` method and give your own sort anonymous function (see Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\SortableIterator)

Comment: @YannEugoné Can you give me code example with anonymous function in my case?

Comment: $finder->sort(function ($a, $b) {
            return strcmp($b->getRealpath(), $a->getRealpath());
        });

Comment: @Victor You mean by modified time DESC?

Comment: @COil, Yes, or at least by filename DESC

Comment: Ok, so @YannEugoné answer seems good. BTW it could be nice to had the feature to the finder component.

Comment: I agree with this, as this is not simple to reuse or modify the standard behaviors of the SortableIterator...

Comment: @YannEugoné How you know that in anonymous function passed 2 arguments in your example? I don't understand (

Comment: This is all about sorting tips. It's always the same thing with that kind of job. Please take a look to http://fr2.php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php. But to be more precise, I've just take a code snipet from the Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\SortableIterator, and I've reverted the return condition.

Comment: @YannEugoné, Thanks, I understand! Can you post your comment as answer to my question and I accepted it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may use the sort method and give your own sort anonymous function (see `Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\SortableIterator`)

```
$finder->sort(function ($a, $b) { return strcmp($b->getRealpath(), $a->getRealpath()); });
```

This is all about sorting tips.
It's always the same thing with that kind of job.
Please take a look to the [usort function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

To be more precise, I've just take a code snipet from `Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\SortableIterator`, and I've reverted the return condition.

Answer (score 8):

The **reverseSorting** method, that was introduced in Symfony 4.2, can be used now.

```
$finder = new Finder();
$finder->sortByModifiedTime();
$finder->reverseSorting();
$finder->files()->in( $directoryPath );

foreach ($finder as $file) {
  // log each modification time for example 
  // $this->logger->debug ( \date('d/m/Y H:i', $file->getMTime()) );
}
```

[Github commit](https://github.com/symfony/finder/commit/3f265e9585d22c6cb5bf27cc66cc6be18bb49cb2#diff-72f194dc8a335e3d4455dbd9bbd0dd6f)

Answer (score 6):

In Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\SortableIterator you can see the ASC case, so the DESC case is:

```
$finder->files()->in($this->getDumpPath())->sort(
    function ($a, $b) {
       return ($b->getMTime() - $a->getMTime());
    }
);
```